# Can I chain these 2 ".last" lodash calls?

Tags: angular, lodash

I have a loan object with an  array of credit report history and each credit report has an array of credit scores.   I want to get the last credit score of the last credit report

```
let creditReportHistory = loanInfo.creditReportHistory;
let lastReport = creditReportHistory ? _.last(creditReportHistory) : null;
let lastScore = lastReport ? _.last(lastReport.creditScores) : null;
return (
  loanInfo.fico !== null &&          // has a score
  _.isArray(creditReportHistory) &&  // history is an array
  creditReportHistory.length > 0 &&  // at least one credit report
  lastScore === null                 // last report has a last score that is null
);
```

The above code basically needs to know if the last score of the last report is null.   The other conditions don't  rely on the lodash "last()" calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be your solution, but I don't have a dataset to test it against, so I was just trying to replicate your logic.

```js
// Your current code:
let creditReportHistory = loanInfo.creditReportHistory;
let lastReport = creditReportHistory ? _.last(creditReportHistory) : null;
let lastScore = lastReport ? _.last(lastReport.creditScores) : null;
return (
  loanInfo.fico !== null &&          // has a score
  _.isArray(creditReportHistory) &&  // history is an array
  creditReportHistory.length > 0 &&  // at least one credit report
  lastScore === null                 // last report has a last score that is null
);

// Updated:
const lastScore = _.chain(loanInfo.creditReportHistory)
  .last()
  .flatMap((lastReport) => lastReport.creditScores)
  .last()
  .value();

return (
  loanInfo.fico !== null
  && lastScore 
);
```

Comment: Okay, I brought that code block in and am getting an error at compile time that Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type '{ }'.
My data structure (simplified) is this:
loanInfo has the creditReportHistory property, which is an array of CreditReportItems.
CreditReportItem has an ID of type string and a creditScores property which is an array of  numbers.
So the last creditReportHIstory item has an array scores as numbers.
Haven't yet figured out why the compiler doesn't like .flatMap() being applied to the last creditReportHistory.

Comment: If you're getting that message at compile time, then that is TypeScript complaining that it can't infer the types, so you are going to have to do some explicit typecasting. The other option is to import the Lodash types into your project as a `devDependencies` in your application's `package.json` file. That might help TypeScript do the type inference. The package should be `@types/lodash`.